# Using remember in induction over proposition gives 'ill-typed' error in Coq

Tags: coq, induction

Here are the inductive & computational definitions of evenness of natural numbers.

```
Inductive ev : nat -> Prop :=
  | ev_0 : ev O
  | ev_SS : forall n:nat, ev n -> ev (S (S n)).

Definition even (n:nat) : Prop := 
  evenb n = true.
```

And the proof that one implies the other.

```
Theorem ev__even : forall n,
  ev n -> even n.
intros n E.
induction E as [ | n' E' ]. 
reflexivity. apply IHE'. Qed.
```

I didn't think much of this proof at first, but on a closer look I find something troubling. The problem is that after the `reflexivity` step, I expect to see the context

```
1 subgoal
n' : nat
E : ev (S (S n'))
E' : ev n'
IHE' : ev n' -> even n'
====================================================================== (1/1)
even (S (S n'))
```

But what I actually get instead is

```
1 subgoal
n' : nat
E' : ev n'
IHE' : even n'
====================================================================== (1/1)
even (S (S n'))
```

Although the theorem is still provable as is, it is disturbing to see hypotheses mysteriously disappear. I'd like to know how to get the context I initially expected. From web searches I understand that this is a general problem with induction over constructed terms in Coq. [One proposed solution on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554493/coq-induction-over-functions-without-losing-information) suggests using the `remember` tactic on hypotheses to be kept. But when I try that in this proof,

```
Theorem ev__even : forall n,
  ev n -> even n.
intros n E.
remember E.
induction E as [ | n' E' ].
```

I get the following error message at the `induction` step.

```
Error: Abstracting over the term "n" leads to a term
"fun n : nat => forall e : ev n, e = E -> even n" which is ill-typed.
```

Which I do not really understand. I *think* the problem is that `E` has a free variable, but in that case I would be stuck, since there is no way to introduce `E` without also introducing `n`. (`generalize dependent n` would generalize `E` with it)

Is there any way to obtain the initially expected context?

Comment: I don't understand why you expect to see 
`E : ev (S (S n'))` and `IHE' : ev n' -> even n'`

Comment: Never mind, I see that you are right about both.

Comment: If you use the induction principle `forall P, P 0 -> P 1 -> (forall n, P n -> P (S (S n))) -> forall n, P n`, then `ev` will occur in the induction hypothesis like you expect it to. The induction principle for `ev` is `ev_ind`, which has type `forall P, P 0 -> (forall n, ev n -> P n -> P (S (S n))) -> forall n, ev n -> P n`. When performing induction on `ev` you shouldn't expect `ev` to be a premise of the induction hypothesis, just like when performing induction on a `nat` you shouldn't expect a `nat` to be universally quantified in the induction hypothesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what the `induction` tactic is doing here.
Whenever I don't understand what a tactic is doing, I try to just write the proof term myself.
If you invoke the induction principle by hand, you can keep the original hypothesis:

```
Theorem ev__even : forall n, ev n -> even n.
  intros n E.
  refine (ev_ind even _ _ n E).
  - reflexivity.
  - intros n' E' IH.
    apply IH.
Qed.
```

This is what the context looks like in the second case of the induction:

```
  n : nat
  E : ev n
  n' : nat
  E' : ev n'
  IH : even n'
  ============================
   even (S (S n'))
```

Assuming

```
Fixpoint evenb (n:nat) : bool :=
  match n with
  | O        => true
  | S O      => false
  | S (S n') => evenb n'
  end.
```

Comment: You can η-reduce the proof by using `refine (ev_ind even _ _)` instead of `intros` and `refine`.

Answer (score 3):

To be useful, the induction tactic tries to generalize over all variables that depend on the thing you are doing induction on, and things that depend on the indices of its type. In your case, this implies generalizing over `n`, the newly generated proof `e : ev n`, and the equality `e = E`. However, it does not generalize over `E` itself, because the induction principles that are automatically generated for propositions ignore the proof argument. Unfortunately, this means that that generalization will be ill-typed, and your intuition is correct: because `E` was not generalized with `n`, its type will mention a different number, which will make the equality `e = E` ill-typed.